# Compare Two Fields in Same Table Within Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need to compare rent for offices within the same table.  Each month has its own column.

I need to find when an increase or decrease in the rent occurs.

I'm looking to show a response once the query runs such as SAME, INCREASE, DECREASE, STOPPED.

I need help with writing the code as when I try it shows I have bad syntax.

Thank you for any and all help provided.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: show your access db model, screenshot... anything that might help us to understand the data. And expected results.

Comment: Plus the code which you have written but gives you an error!

Comment: "Each month has its own column". You need to read up on normalisation. Access is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand the problem from what you describe, but maybe this will help you into the right direction ? I cant figure out the result you expect (if it is a row with all columns and the rent development, or one single result, or one row for each month, etc), but something like below will maybe help you?

```
SELECT  
initialvalue, 
jan, 
switch(
    jan = initialvalue, 'SAME'
  , jan > initialvalue, 'INCREASE'
  , jan < initialvalue, 'DECREASE'
  , jan = 0, 'STOPPED'
  ) as JanChange,
feb,
switch(
    feb = jan, 'SAME'
  , feb > jan, 'INCREASE'
  , feb < jan, 'DECREASE'
  , feb = 0, 'STOPPED'
  ) as FebChange 
-- continue here with the rest of the months...
FROM Rents
;
```

[image]